# LaTeX formatting error in iPython QtConsole

Tags: python, latex, ipython, sympy, qtconsole

Running into this bug (among other LaTeX formatting issues on iPython QtConsole):

```
In[52]: abs(x).diff()
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py:239: FormatterWarning: Exception in   image/png formatter: Expected end of math '$'
$\left(\Re{x} \frac{d}{d x} \Re{x} + \Im{x} \frac{d}{d x} \Im{x}\right) /\left\lvert{x}\right\rvert$ (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
  FormatterWarning,
Out[52]: 
      d                 d        
re(x)⋅──(re(x)) + im(x)⋅──(im(x))
      dx                dx       
─────────────────────────────────
               │x│
```

Python, iPython, and sympy are all up to date. Any insights onto why this error is occurring? It started appearing after I upgraded to OS X 10.9.

Comment: Try sympy 0.7.6 (there is currently only a release candidate at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/releases/tag/sympy-0.7.6.rc2, but the final version will be released within a week).